# Android Firebase authentication using Phone number

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-digits

Has anyone tried using firebase authentication with phone number in android? I didn't find documentation for this in firebase docs. Or can I use the steps described in fabric digits? But The Digits SDK will be retired fully after some time. Please point me to docs/reference URLs. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

[Phone Auth for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) is now available.

---

From [What's New in Firebase (Google I/O '17)](https://youtu.be/m7a26ymUu2U?t=13m4s):

> "*Firebase (Phone) Auth is available today on [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) and [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth), with Android rolling out in the coming weeks.*"

If you just modify the URL for iOS/Web to [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth), it will show you a page that says:

> **Authenticate with Firebase using Phone Numbers on Android**
>
> Phone number sign-in is coming soon to Firebase on Android. Check this page in early June 2017 for details.

<sub>PS: The date has the possibility to change, all depending on Google.</sub>

Comment: Sadly it's postpone to early June now. Still waiting for them :(

Comment: @BoonyaKitpitak Thanks for the notice. I updated the post.

Comment: The Android Phone auth is live now :)